# how to perform event on flex line

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flex4.5

How to perform event on flex line objects.so i can able to move or re-size the line using mouse.I am using flexline as shown in below code:-

```
spark.primitives.Line;
var st:Stroke =new Stroke(0x345654,1,1);                
var obj:Line = new Line();
obj.stroke =st;
obj.xFrom =0;
obj.yFrom=0;
obj.xTo = 500;
obj.yTo = 500;
obj.addEventListener =????? //how to resize this line using mouse??
```

please explain how to addeventlistner on line or give any other idea to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. `Line` is not an `InteractiveObject`.

You can add it to a group and then listen to its events,

or draw a line with `graphics` on `Sprite` and listen to sprite events(this is more lightweight).

Or you may add all graphic primitives like `Line` to group and calculate by code which line appeared under group click.

Comment: If i use group then i face problem with points localtoglobal and globaltolocal. How to manage line x and y with group x and y on canvas. is this complex? or simple way to handle?

Comment: Why do you face such problems? If you click on group which does not have any interactive children, then you have click coordinates for group in `localX` and `localY` properties of `MouseEvent`.  Anyways, as soon as group is scrollable, you may want to use `contentToGlobal` instead of `localToGlobal`.

Comment: my problem is add line control(connect objects,joints) on diagrams like www.cacoo.com

Comment: Your problem looks like complex project. Try to extract more small problems from it which will fit the format of Q/A for this site.